# qt creator does not see the qwt headers

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake, qwt

I have installed qwt as it explained [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/53787-HowTo-Installation-of-Qt-5-0-1-and-Qwt-6-1-0-rc3-%28Win7-64bit%29). The problem is that compiler can not find qwt headers. When I type `#include <qwt_plot_h>` `in mainwindow.cpp` file, compiler gives an error: qwt_plot.h:No such file or directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this into your project file:

```
CONFIG  += qxt
QXT     += core gui
```

You could invoke qmake like this, e.g. on Windows:

```
qmake -set QMAKEFEATURES C:\Qwt-6.1.0\features
```

Comment: doesn't help. I have added the next lines:        CONFIG+=qwt
        CONFIG+=qxt
        QXT+=core qui

Comment: @lnk: which platform, compiler, qt, etc are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 8 64 bit. Qt Creator 3.1.1, Qt 5.2.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit), MinGW 4.8 32 bit. I can add qwt widgets in Qt Designer, but there are now trace of qwt in Qt Creator

Comment: @lnk: does it work if you manually add the include and lib paths (`-L) and lib name (`-l`) to INCLUDEPATH and LIBS? Also, you could try `qmake -set QMAKEFEATURES C:\Qwt-$VERSION\features`.

Comment: I have put that lines to my .pro file:`INCLUDEPATH+="C:\Qwt-6.1.0\include"
INCLUDEPATH+="C:\Qwt-6.1.0\lib"`. Now it's ok with headers. But when I type this: `QwtPlot *plot=new QwtPlot(this);` compiler gives an error: Undefined reference to `QwtPlot::QwtPlot(QWinget*)`

Comment: What does `qxt` to do with `qwt`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SUBDIRS += "C:\qwt-6.1.4\src"
```

to make QWT consider all the requested headers and their source files in QWT source directory.